# Error 404 for centos-sclo-rh-release when trying to install oVirt 4.2

Tags: virtualization, centos7, package-management, ovirt

**Hello there,**

I am trying to install oVirt 4.2 on my CentOS 7.4 machine.

Unfortunately, yum keeps telling me that he cannot find `http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/repodata/repomd.xml.asc:` on the only mirror for `centos-sclo-rh-release`.

I don't think I have forgotten anything on the [official doc](https://www.ovirt.org/documentation/install-guide/chap-Installing_oVirt/). So I did this :

1. I updated the whole system.
2. I installed the [required keys](https://www.ovirt.org/download/#importing-keys-manually).
3. I installed [this package](http://resources.ovirt.org/pub/yum-repo/ovirt-release42.rpm)
4. I made sure one more time that my system was updated and **thats when things went wrong** .

Here is an exact copy of what yum told me :

```
[root@jupiter admin]# yum update
Modules complémentaires chargés : fastestmirror
base/7/x86_64/signature                                         |  811 B  00:00:00     
base/7/x86_64/signature                                         | 3.6 kB  00:00:00 !!! 
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/repodata/repomd.xml.asc: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
Essai d'un autre miroir.
To address this issue please refer to the below wiki article 

https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors

If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.

centos-sclo-rh-release                                          | 3.0 kB  00:00:00     


 One of the configured repositories failed (CentOS-7 - SCLo rh),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=centos-sclo-rh-release ...

     4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
        will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
        again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable centos-sclo-rh-release
        or
            subscription-manager repos --disable=centos-sclo-rh-release

     5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=centos-sclo-rh-release.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml.asc from centos-sclo-rh-release: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/x86_64/rh/repodata/repomd.xml.asc: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404 - Not Found
```

**EDIT:**
So here is the content of my ovirt-4.2-dependancies.repo which contains centos-sclo-rh-release :

```
[admin@jupiter ~]$ cat /etc/yum.repos.d/ovirt-4.2-dependencies.repo 
[ovirt-4.2-epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - $basearch
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-7&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
includepkgs=
 epel-release,
 ioprocess,
 libtomcrypt,
 libtommath,
 ovirt-guest-agent*,
 puppet,
 python2-crypto,
 python2-ecdsa,
 python2-paramiko,
 python34*,
 python-argparse,
 python-ecdsa,
 python-ioprocess,
 python-ordereddict,
 python-paramiko,
 python-ply,
 rubygem-rgen,
 nbdkit,
 nbdkit-devel

gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7

[ovirt-4.2-centos-gluster312]
name=CentOS-7 - Gluster 3.12
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/storage/$basearch/gluster-3.12/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CentOS-Storage-SIG/centos-release-storage-common/master/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-Storage


[ovirt-4.2-virtio-win-latest]
name=virtio-win builds roughly matching what will be shipped in upcoming RHEL
baseurl=http://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/repo/latest
enabled=1
skip_if_unavailable=1
gpgcheck=0

[ovirt-4.2-centos-qemu-ev]
name=CentOS-7 - QEMU EV
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/virt/$basearch/kvm-common/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-Virtualization

[ovirt-4.2-centos-opstools]
name=CentOS-7 - OpsTools - release
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/opstools/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-OpsTools

[centos-sclo-rh-release]
name=CentOS-7 - SCLo rh
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/sclo/$basearch/rh/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-SCLo

[ovirt-4.2-centos-ovirt42]
name=CentOS-7 - oVirt 4.2
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/virt/$basearch/ovirt-4.2/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.centos.org/keys/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-SIG-Virtualization
```

Comment: That file doesn't exist. I wonder why it's looking for it at all? Have you looked at the .repo file?

Comment: Hum yeah but what should I look for ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seems that I've chosen a far too strict security policy during the installation process. To solve this, I had to set

```
repo_gpgcheck=1
```

back to

```
repo_gpgcheck=0
```

in `/etc/yum.conf`.